# Rails Complex Query Suggesting Next Object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, named-scope, rails-models

I have a complex scope on my model giving the user active deals that meet their parameters.

```
scope :deal_query, lambda { |m, p| where("meal = ? and active = ? and people LIKE '%?%' and inactive_days NOT LIKE '%?%'", m, true, p, Time.zone.now.wday)}
```

The people column is serialized and stores an array of numbers (its a hack to use the LIKE sql statement to search a serialized column). I then pass this array of data to a map! block, which renders all the data in a hash.

Heres a trimmed down version of the block. (side note, I am using rails as an API and this returns json)

```
Deal.deal_query(params[:meal].to_i, people).map! {|ld| {                                                                                            
:deal_id => ld.id, :title => ld.title, :description => ld.description}}
```

In the block, I am also trying to send the name of next available deal by incrementing the people column by 1. I do not want to run a separate query in the block checking for the next available deal, this would be incredibly inefficient as it scaled.

Any suggestions on how to eager load the next available deal would be helpful. I thought about creating another scope with just incrementing the people column by 1 but then I dont know how I would match it with the data from the first scope.

Answer (score 0):

Why not change your LIKE to:

```
where("... (people LIKE '%?%' OR people LIKE '%?%') ...", <etc>, p, p+1, <etc>)
```

In other words, grab both in one go, then do what you need to with the results.  I'm not very clear on what your goal is with the `map!` call and what you mean by "name of the next available deal", but you should be able to pull out whatever data you need from the objects at that point as you'll have the full AR model to play with.

If you want more help on scalability, would need to see the DB schema.  This feels pretty hacktastic just from what you've shown - there's likely a more elegant and performant way to deal with the people column...

Comment: Should note, the way you have things set up now, you'll run into trouble with `people LIKE '%10%'` matching with people == 10, 100, 101, 10050, etc.  If you stick with this, I'd hand-serialize your data using a post character like :, so your in-db people list would look like ':5:50:280:', then change your like to `LIKE '%:?:%'` (note the guard colons)

Comment: Thank you for your answer... The people column will never be above 12 so I should run into any of the matching problems. Using the 'OR' call will help eager load it but then I will need to parse the array that is returned. The map! call should go through each object that matches the constrains, I dont want to to go through the objects with people +1. I just need it to grab the name of the people +1 deal.

Comment: So then, how will you select people == 1 without also selecting people == 10, 11 and 12?  :-)  As for handling the resulting array, I agree that's an issue, but I don't see a way around it.  SQL doesn't have a "next" operator or similar - your only solution would be to do a sub-select for the next name, and that would get you back to  having two select calls for each item.  Could you pre-calc the "next" value and add it as a column to the main item somehow?